# Buscar es una base de datos con una variable ingresada por el usuario

Tags: python, base-de-datos, sqlite

Tengo una duda, quisiera saber como buscar en una base de datos si quiero ingresar desde consola el objeto a buscar, es decir; no quiero declararlo en el código sino que el usuario ingrese el parámetro para que el código busque en la base de datos e imprima el resultado.

El código es como pensaba que funcionaria, pero evidentemente no lo hizo:

```
Pr = input()
cursor1.execute("SELECT * FROM DATOS_CLIENTES00 WHERE Nombre='Pr'")
datoss=cursor1.fetchall()
print(datoss)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu query es una cadena estática, es literalmente:

```
"SELECT * FROM DATOS_CLIENTES00 WHERE Nombre='Pr'"
```

simplemente debes parametrizarla, con la entrada del usuario como valor del parámetro:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("ruta/a/bd")
cursor = conn.cursor()

nombre = input("Ingrese el nombre a buscar: "):
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM DATOS_CLIENTES00 WHERE Nombre=?", (nombre,))
datos = cursor.fetchall()
print(datos)

conn.close()
```

Comment: Geaciaaaaaas c: